# When deploying Google App Script Add-On appscript.json code changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I've been trying to update my add-on in the Google Workspace Marketplace and every time I try to deploy, my manifest file (appscript.json) changes, making it impossible to deploy a new version of my add-on.

https://youtu.be/PcNn39z9pac

Does anyone know why this is happening / what I can do to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194030371).  [Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68456037/googe-app-script-apsscript-json-is-changed-when-deploying-new-datastudio-connec). Currently you can work around this by using the legacy editor's `Deploy from Manifest`.